# Tomcat removeAbandoned property causing exception

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, configuration

I am trying to add the removeAbandoned attribute to a resource in an environment running Tomcat 5.5.    Before adding this attribute, the servlet running in this environment works fine.   As soon as I add the attribute an exception is thrown as follows:

EXCEPTION javax.naming.NamingException: No set method found for property: removeAbandoned.

I do not understand why this is happenning.  As soon as I remove the attribute, the servlet works again.

Below is the entire Context tag as it appears in my environment:

```
<Context path="/emscribe" docBase="emscribe" debug="0" reloadable="true"  
crossContext="true"> 

 <Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger" prefix="emscribe_log." 
 suffix=".txt" timestamp="true"/> 

 <Resource name="jdbc/emscribe" auth="Container" 
 type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  
  maxPoolSize="100"  minPoolSize="5"   

 acquireIncrement="5"  removeAbandoned="true"
  user="aUserID"  

 password="aPassword"

 factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"   

  jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://127.000.71.101/emscribedx?autoReconnect=true" 
 />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: No set method found for property: removeAbandoned.
```

states that it can't find a method `getRemoveAbandoned()` and `setRemoveAbandoned(boolean removeAbandoned)` from the type specified in your resource.

The `removeAdandoned` property can only be used with Apache [DBCP BasicDataSource](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html).

So, your resource `jdbc/emscribe` type must not be `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource` but rather `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

removeAdandoned would not work with cp30 connection pooling. Its for DBCP on older tomcat versions or apache connection pooling introduced in tomcat 7